# Run executables in gradlew

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

How can I run the `mvn` executable from the gradle wrapper?

```
 task install(type: Exec, dependsOn: assemble) {
   description = "Som description."
   executable = 'mvn'
   args = ["install:install-file", <more-args-here>]
 }
```

I can access the command from the terminal normally. I also added `MAVEN_HOME` in the Path Variables but looks like gradlew can still not find the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your OS. If you are on Windows try to rewrite your task into this

```
task install(type: Exec, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "Som description."
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'mvn', 'install:install-file', <more-args-here>
}
```

On linux go for

```
task install(type: Exec, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "Som description."
    commandLine './mvn', 'install:install-file', <more-args-here>
}
```